# Azure Databricks - Are there any best practices while creating folder structure in workspace and managing permissions on folders?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have provisioned a new databricks workspace for production and want to create folders inside based on some best practices or pointers.

Also I want to manage the permissions to these folders.

What are the key points to take care of, while provisioning a clean production databricks workspace?

Comment: Do you want to apply the permissions on the folder level using Workspace access control in Azure Databricks, where the workspace visibility control is by default enable in the Azure Databricks platform version 3.34, if an older version need to enable manually. might be achieved via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/workspace-acl#--folder-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find azure Databricks best practices [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/databricks/best-practices-index) for users and administrators.

Git Hub reference doc for [Azure Databricks Best Practices](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDatabricksBestPractices/blob/master/toc.md)

Folders: Folders contain all static assets within a workspace: notebooks, libraries, experiments, and other folders. Icons indicate the type of the object contained in a folder. [Workspace objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workspace/workspace-objects) An Azure Databricks workspace has three special folders: Workspace, Shared, and Users.You cannot rename or move a special folder.

Permissions: By default, all users can create and modify workspace objects—including folders, notebooks, experiments, and models—unless an administrator enables workspace access control.You can assign five permission levels to folders: No Permissions, Read, Run, Edit, and Manage. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/workspace-acl#--folder-permissions) for permissions. Access control is available only in the Azure Databricks Premium Plan.